# LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Trying to install LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) on  Ubuntu 16.04 and test to see if apache server is set up properly.

Cant figure out this error.

The apache service is already installed but i am trying to test it with this command - C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\apache24\bin\httpd -S

It gives me this error.

httpd: Syntax error on line 535 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from

This is line that is giving the error.

535 LoadModule php 5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
536 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
537 # configure the path to php.ini
538 PHPIniDir "C:/php"

This is my first time setting up a server and any other assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a space between php and 5_module in that command. If there is, that's probably the problem.